# Getting sense stems for nltk semcor corpus words

Tags: nlp, nltk, google-colaboratory, nltk-book

I was trying semcor corpus in nltk.

I found this code [here](https://www.nltk.org/howto/corpus.html):

```
>>> list(map(str, semcor.tagged_chunks(tag='both')[:3])) 
['(DT The)', "(Lemma('group.n.01.group') (NE (NNP Fulton County Grand Jury)))", "(Lemma('state.v.01.say') (VB said))"]
```

I tried the same on colab (check last cell in [this](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/16YaSo_m_WE3Wi11FpaQRYjWQ_flv1LzK#scrollTo=Qaivs-I5xodN&line=1&uniqifier=1) notebook):

```
>>> list(map(str, semcor.tagged_chunks(tag='both')[:3]))
['(DT The)',
 '(group.n.01 (NE (NNP Fulton County Grand Jury)))',
 '(say.v.01 (VB said))']
```

Here is the screenshot from colab:

[image]

**The problem**

Note that on nltk page, for `Fulton County Grand Jury` output is given as `Lemma('group.n.01.group')`, but on colab, I am getting `group.n.01`. So I am not getting sense / synset lemma.

- In `group.n.01.group`

  - first `group` is a "stem for sense word"
  - last `group` is "stem for input"
- In `group.n.01`

  - (first and only) `group` is "stem for input"
  - no "stem for sense word" is returned

Weird thing is that it was giving me correct output yesterday. [This](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ua8OTpw273fFf0hcVU4VgtEFjfjAVzQN?usp=sharing) notebook will clear the doubt as it has same two lines executed today and yesterday. Yesterday (2/9/2021), I was getting tags in format `group.n.01.group`, but today I am getting tags in `group.n.01` format (**NOTICE RED AND BLUE COMMENTS**):

[image]

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew that `semcor` uses `wordnet` senses to tag to subset of `brown` corpus. But I was not aware that [`semcor` APIs](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html#nltk.corpus.reader.semcor.SemcorCorpusReader) can work with or without `wordnet` predownloaded and it will give tags in different format in these different scenarios. I honestly feel, at least `semcor` API documentation should have some mention of this.

So, without `wordnet` predownloaded, it does not return sense stems:

[image]

With `wordnet` pre-downloaded, it does return sense stems:

[image]